# Karma basePath is defaulting to C:\

Tags: javascript, karma-runner, gulp, karma-jasmine

I am trying to run jasmine Specs through karma but when karma looks for my included files it uses a basepath of `C:\` even though the configuration file is in `C:\dev\project\`.

I am running Karma in a gulp task:

```
var karma = require('karma').server;
gulp.task('test', function (done) {
    karma.start({configFile: '../../../karma.conf.js', singleRun: true}, done);
});
```

The settings that relate to this issue:

```
basePath: '',
files: [
 {patterns:'bower_components/**/*.js',included:true},
 {patterns:'src/*.js', included:true},
 {patterns:'tests/*Spec.js', included:true}
],
exclude: []
```

When I run `gulp test` the log from karma spits out this:

```
WARN [watcher]: Pattern "C:/bower_components/**/*.js" does not match any file.
WARN [watcher]: Pattern "C:/src/*.js" does not match any file.
WARN [watcher]: Pattern "C:/tests/*Spec.js" does not match any file.
```

I'm new to karma and am not really sure what the issue is here. I tried a `basePath` of `''`, `'./'`, and `'/'`.

Comment: Please add the tag `javascript` to the question, it will add syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set the basePath to the local CWD directory path with:

```
basePath: process.cwd(), //  this gets the path which gulp is running in terminal
files: [
 {patterns:'bower_components/**/*.js',included:true},
 {patterns:'src/*.js', included:true},
 {patterns:'tests/*Spec.js', included:true}
],
exclude: []
```

`process.cwd()` gets the CLI path, the path which node is running in the terminal.